# Django view got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a following url pattern:

```
urlpatterns = pattern('',
    ...
    url(r'edit-offer/(?P<id>\d+)/$', login_required(edit_offer), name='edit_offer'),
)
```

and a corresponding edit_offer view:

```
def edit_offer(request, id):
  # do stuff here
```

a link on offer page leads to edit offer view:

```
<a class="btn" href="{% url edit_offer offer.id %}">Edit</a>
```

clicking on the button throws a TypeError:

```
edit_offer() got an unexpected keyword argument 'offer_id'
```

Any ideas what is going on? I don't see what's wrong here. I have other views with similar patterns and they all work ok.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

Your `urls.py`:-

```
urlpatterns = pattern('whatever_your_app.views',
    ...
    url(r'edit-offer/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'edit_offer', name='edit_offer'),
)
```

Your `views.py`:-

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

...

@login_required
def edit_offer(request, id):
    # do stuff here
```

and in your `template`:-

```
{% url 'edit_offer' offer.id %}
```

Comment: thank you. following your advice, when i came to type in a full path to my offer, i found out i had another view (dummy) with the same name, and that offer indeed didnt have offer_id among its kwargs, removing it solved my problem. Dumb mistake on my part.