# django got unexpected keyword argument after adding middleware

Tags: python, django

> I have read source code of django's admin view ,the view doesn't
>   accept keyword argument.
>
> Now the question is ,how can i pass my own variables to django's admin
>   view except extend django's default view?
>
> I don't want to change default view and its url settings,can i extend
>   it by other way?

I write my own django middleware to pass my public variable to all of my view.

But,after it,i meet django got unexpected keyword argument  when i use djano admin views.

I can not find any help about this problem,nor can i find example from django's documention.

Following links are what i found.

[Django view got an unexpected keyword argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439399/django-view-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument)

["got an unexpected keyword argument 'ticket_id'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166931/got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-ticket-id)

I will list my code below:

middleware.py

```
from blog.data import (UserInfo,BasicInfo,APost,HeaderMenu,PostSummary,TagsGetter,
                       ArchivesIndex,PostsGetter,CommentsGetter,TTypeGetter,LinkGetter)

class data_md(object):
    """pass some kwargs to view to share public data"""
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        #if 'djangoadmin' not in request.path:
        if True:
            view_kwargs['posts_getter'] = PostsGetter()
            view_kwargs['user_info'] = UserInfo(request)
            view_kwargs['basic_info'] = BasicInfo(request)
            view_kwargs['header_menu'] = HeaderMenu()
            view_kwargs['comments_getter'] = CommentsGetter()
            view_kwargs['tags_getter'] = TagsGetter()
            view_kwargs['ttype_getter'] = TTypeGetter()
            view_kwargs['link_getter'] = LinkGetter()
            return view_func(request, view_args, view_kwargs)
```

blog views.py

```
def tags_view(request, args, data):
    tag = data.get('tagname',None)
    tags_getter = data.get('tags_getter',None)
    if tag in tags_getter.tagnamelist: 
        from blog.data import get_summarys_bytag
        post_summarys = get_summarys_bytag(tag)
        return render_to_response('blog/read_bytags.html',locals())
    else:
        raise Http404
```

Note:This view works well.but django's admin view doesn't work.

Error Message:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1/djangoadmin/

Django Version: 1.5.4
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'blog')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware',
 'blog.middleware.data_md')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  109.                         response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)
File "/root/win7/app/django/pycms/blog/middleware.py" in process_view
  20.             return view_func(request, *view_args, **view_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in wrapper
  219.                 return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  91.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  89.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  202.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  89.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /djangoadmin/
Exception Value: index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'header_menu'
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From django doc:

> process_view() is called just before Django calls the view.
>
> It should return either None or an HttpResponse object. If it returns
>   None, Django will continue processing this request, executing any
>   other process_view() middleware and, then, the appropriate view. If it
>   returns an HttpResponse object, Django won’t bother calling any other
>   view or exception middleware, or the appropriate view; it’ll apply
>   response middleware to that HttpResponse, and return the result.

You should not call the view_func yourself, instead you should attach those attributes  into the request  object and return None. Let Django handle the view function. Returning the response object of the view call also prevent other middlewares processing the request an d may raise other errors later.

e.g.

```
def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
    request.extra_attrs = {}
    request.extra_attrs['posts_getter'] = PostsGetter()
    request.extra_attrs['user_info'] = UserInfo(request)
    request.extra_attrs['basic_info'] = BasicInfo(request)
    request.extra_attrs['header_menu'] = HeaderMenu()
    request.extra_attrs['comments_getter'] = CommentsGetter()
    request.extra_attrs['tags_getter'] = TagsGetter()
    request.extra_attrs['ttype_getter'] = TTypeGetter()
    request.extra_attrs['link_getter'] = LinkGetter()
```

The official django middleware doc lacks real code examples.

The articles below provides some examples.

[Effective Django Understanding Middleware](http://effectivedjango.com/middleware.html)

[The Django Book: Chapter 17: Middleware](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter17.html)

Comment: thanks for your help :),this method works well.Now it seems that django don't allow us to change its keyword argument during its passing.In middleward handler source code , i can not find anything to help me to draw a conclusion.Ohterwise,in Django's own middleware source code i can not find sth about process_view().

Comment: In this case,i can use process_request() function instead of process_view(),but what is the value of the process_view's existence. :)

Comment: @kidneywin yeah. process_view is a little overkill here. process_request is enough. Though you can't change view args, you can get args in process_view() and act differently based on different args.

Comment: Suddenly i found you are  a chinese.First time i saw the time you answered me really scared me! if you are an American,it is time for deep sleep."What a hard man" occrrs in my head.